# How to give image instead of text in pager?

Tags: 6, theming, paging

I need to change the text in to image in pager.

For example:

```
<< First < Previous  4 5 6 7  Next > Last >>
```

Now instead of the above i need to print as below:

```
<< <  4 5 6 7  > >>
```

**Note:** Consider the less than and greater than symbol as images.

**Here is the syntax :**

```
theme_pager_next($text, $limit, $element = 0, $parameters = array())
```

**Here is my code :**

```
$li_next = theme('pager_next', theme_image(drupal_get_path("theme", "fluid") . "/images/text.gif"));
```

**My output is as follows for the above code :**

```
<img src="/sites/all/themes/fluid/images/text.gif" alt="" title="" width="7" height="13" />
```

**But my desired output is to print the image which is in the image tag.**

Any help will be thankful and grateful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just curious, what is keeping you from using CSS image replacement to do this?

Comment: @@Logi: By also using CSS it can be done. But i am in eager to know what mistake i did and to what is the correct way to do it... So in near future i will not do these kind of errors.. :)

Comment: Could you explain what "print the image which is in the image tag" means? Do you want to print the binary contents of that image? Or just the path to the image?

Comment: @@berkes: I just need to print the image. That's what i mean there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [How to change text-links to image links in the pager](http://drupal.org/node/318565).
By using the `theme_image()` function Drupal should nicely format the `<img>` tag, and output it to your theme. Well, this works, but unfortunately somewhere in this `theme_pager()` process a `l()` is telling Drupal to only output plain text here.

The trick here is not to rewrite your whole pager functions. Have a look at [theme_pager_link()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/theme_pager_link/6); this function is building all the links that are used by the pager functions. When you look closer to the `l()` formatting the output is done using the following code:

```
return l($text, $_GET['q'], array('attributes' => $attributes, 'query' => count($query) ? implode('&', $query) : NULL));
```

You'll see the options aren't setting the HTML output. So I placed the whole function in my template.php (changing `theme_pager_link()` to `landrush_pager_lin()k) with a different output:

```
return l($text, $_GET['q'], array('attributes' => $attributes, 'html' => TRUE, 'query' => count($query) ? implode('&', $query) : NULL));
```

Note `'html' => TRUE`.

Now `l()` is allowing me to print HTML tags (images!) within the pager function.